# How can I apply a basic filter to the Xamarin Camera2 preview?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-camera2

My Xamarin Forms app is running a preview using Camera2, which streams nicely. I need to take out the red channel from the preview feed. I've tried creating a LightingColorFilter, but I can't see a way of applying it to any TextureView or other type used in rendering of the stream.

Is it possible to apply a filter to the preview stream from Camera2 without using a separate library? I'd like to use the Android hardware as per best practice if at all possible. I'd share code, but I doubt it'd help - it's essentially https://github.com/UNIT-23/Xam-Android-Camera2-Sample with the click handling removed so far.

Comment: ,According to your description, you want to filter preview stream,generally we filter based on the date or other What do you filter by?

Comment: I want to remove the entire red channel from the preview stream or boost the green and blue (cyan). I don't want to do anything with dates.

Comment: ,Do you solved your issue now, any update?

Comment: Nothing so far, Cherry. Thanks for asking. I think I'm going to try to add click handling, take the user to another page which shows the processed static image, which I should be able to transform as required. It's a shame, but I can't get it to work on the preview stream.